# I'm not sure how to code this, I'm want to make it stop spamming after a keyword but I don't know how to go about it

Tags: python, discord.py

```
@commands.has_role("Bot Developer")
async def spampls(ctx):
  Spamcheck = True
  await ctx.send('What do you want me to spam?')
  def check(m):
    return m.author.id == ctx.author.id
  Spam_Message = await bot.wait_for('message', check=check)
  TrueSpam = Spam_Message.content
  while Spamcheck:
    await ctx.channel.send(TrueSpam)
  Spamcheck2 = await bot.wait_for('message', check=check)
  if Spamcheck2.content.lower == 'stopspam':
    Spamcheck = False
```

So this is the code, I want to make it so that it keeps spamming until the person specifically says "stopspam"
I also tried it like this

```
@commands.has_role("Bot Developer")
async def spampls(ctx):
  Spamcheck = True
  await ctx.send('What do you want me to spam?')
  def check(m):
    return m.author.id == ctx.author.id
  Spam_Message = await bot.wait_for('message', check=check)
  TrueSpam = Spam_Message.content
  while Spamcheck:
    await ctx.channel.send(TrueSpam)

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
@commands.has_role("Bot Developer")
async def stopspam(ctx):
  Spamcheck = False
```

But both don't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use global variables for this in python:

```py
@bot.command()
@commands.has_role("Bot Developer")
async def spampls(ctx):
  global Spamcheck
  Spamcheck = True
  
  [...]

  while Spamcheck:
    await ctx.channel.send(TrueSpam)

@bot.command()
@commands.has_role("Bot Developer")
async def stopspam(ctx):
  global Spamcheck
  Spamcheck = False
```